# How do I request the AWS spot instances pricing from rest API using python

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services

What is the rest API to get the AWS spot instances Pricing? Please provide some examples.
Thanks

Siva

Comment: AWS has some fantastic documentation. Can you tell us which part of the documentation needs some clarification? It will make it easier to help you with the problem.

Comment: I am running some of the spot instances in AWS. so I need to get those instance_type costs. Because AWS cost will be changing over a period of time. So every time, it is difficult to manually create a cost file. That's why I would like to get all instance_types with their prices through REST API.

Answer (score 0):

The spot price can vary continually. To discover the **actual** spot price charged for instance you are running, use the [Spot Instance Data Feed - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-data-feeds.html):

> To help you understand the charges for your Spot Instances, Amazon EC2 provides a **data feed** that describes your Spot Instance usage and pricing. This data feed is sent to an Amazon S3 bucket that you specify when you subscribe to the data feed.

To obtain general historical information about spot pricing, use [Spot Instance Pricing History - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-instances-history.html).

Comment: how to create the prefix in the below command                                                           aws ec2 create-spot-datafeed-subscription --bucket myawsbucket [--prefix myprefix]         could you please provide some examples to explore the ec2 spot instances from local machine